# Is JAVA_HOME not required anymore for recent versions of Maven?

Tags: java, maven, java-home

Few days ago, I observed, that `mvn -version` runs successfully even without having `JAVA_HOME` defined. As I remember, historically, all Maven versions needed `JAVA_HOME`.

So, I've played a bit, downloaded different versions of Maven and tested them.

It turns out, that Maven versions <= 3.5.3 were in a need of `JAVA_HOME` in order to know where to refer for running Java runtime; however, Maven versions >= 3.5.4 do not anymore necessarily need `JAVA_HOME` and they run fine without it.

Moreover, `mvn -version` with any Maven <= 3.5.3 prints:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (f9f2937f9f29f9f293df5050c2f9f29f9f295297; 2018-02-24T21:49:05+02:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

while `mvn -version` with any Maven >= 3.5.4 prints:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (11c987ce5ffb2f3e7767ce5ffb20915ffb20c987; 2018-10-24T21:41:47+03:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: c:\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

First is with `JAVA_HOME` and second - without.

So, do we still need to be providing `JAVA_HOME` for Maven in the future or not?

If yes - how it works without `JAVA_HOME`?

If no - why? because of what exact reason?

Comment: I would recommend to provide JAVA_HOME... that's the cleanest way. BTW: Since 3.5.4 there has been a change in the output (see https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.4/release-notes.html) ...

Comment: @khmarbaise but why? what does" cleanest way" mean? if it explicitly states, that `jdk/bin` on PATH is enough.. why would I consider JAVA_HOME as a cleanest way? :)

Comment: On many systems the java on path is something different than provided via `JAVA_HOME` (for example using sdkman or alike) and also on linux systems default installed system provided JDK is often not what you like to use... that's why I call `JAVA_HOME` the cleanest way because it's relying **NOT** on PATH nor on defaults or alike.. only on `JAVA_HOME` itself.

Comment: BTW: Use most recent versions of Maven.. (3.8.7) or even (3.9.0) https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html (if you like to experiment use Maven 4.0.0-alpha-4)...

Answer (score 3):

From https://maven.apache.org/install.html

> Have a JDK installation on your system. Either set the `JAVA_HOME`
> environment variable pointing to your JDK installation or have the
> `java executable` on your `PATH`.

Comment: This partly answers my question, but I'm more into when and why this happened and what's the Maven's official preference (and why).

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, your question may be more like  : why JAVA_HOME is needed for Maven? Anyway I think you can find the answer from the source code of Maven.